# Server side validation and insertion to table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This php file is using server side validation via post method as the user enters data into the input devices. The only problem I'm having is inserting the data into the customers table as it doesn't work. I know this because i have created test php file that displays all the customer tables content and the data the user enters is not there. Where have i gone wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-
    strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Prac 2 Task 12</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    <?php

     $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa291", "......"); 
     mysql_select_db("factory291", $conn) 
     or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() ); 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer"; 
     $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) 
     or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error()); 

    $ename = $elname = $ecus = $epcode = "";
    $fnamecus = $lnamecus = $idcus = $pcde = "";

    $error_report = false;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (empty($_POST["customerid"])) {
         $ecus = "Customer ID is required";
    $error_report = true;
       } else {
         $idcus = input_t($_POST["customerid"]);
         // check if numeric
         if (preg_match("/[^0-9]/",$idcus)) {
           $ecus = "Only numbers allowed"; 
    $error_report = true;
    }
        if(strlen($idcus) != 6 && ($idcus) != null)
    {
          $ecus = "Customer ID must be 6 digits"; 
    $error_report = true;
    }
       }
       if (empty($_POST["customerfname"])) {
         $ename = "First name is required";
    $error_report = true;
       } else {
         $fnamecus= input_t($_POST["customerfname"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-]*$/",$fnamecus)) {
           $ename = "Only alphabetic letters and hyphen";
    $error_report = true; 
         }
        if(strlen($fnamecus) > 20 && ($fnamecus) != null)
    {
          $ename = "First name can't be more that 20 characters long"; 
    $error_report = true;
    }
       }
    if (empty($_POST["customerlname"])) {
         $elname = "Last name is required";
    $error_report = true;
       } else {
         $lnamecus = input_t($_POST["customerlname"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-]*$/",$lnamecus)) {
           $elname = "Only alphabetic letters and hyphen";
    $error_report = true; 
         }
      if(strlen($lnamecus) > 20 && ($lnamecus) != null)
    {
          $elname = "Last name can't be more that 20 characters long";
    $error_report = true; 
    }
       }
    if (!is_null($_POST["postcode"])) {
         $pcde = input_t($_POST["postcode"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (preg_match("/[^0-9]/",$pcde)) {
           $epcode = "Only numbers allowed";
    $error_report = true; 
         }
        if(strlen($pcde) != 4 && ($pcde) != null)
    {
          $epcode = "Post code must be 4 digits";
    $error_report = true; 
    }
      } 
    }
    if($error_report != true) {
    $query="INSERT INTO customer (customerID, firstName, lastName, Address, suburb, state, postcode)
    VALUES ('customerid', 'customerfname', ‘customerlname', 'customeraddress', 'suburb', 
    'state', 'postcode')";
   $queryResult = mysql_query($query, $conn) 
   or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error()); 
    echo "correct";

    }



    function input_t($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }
    ?>


    <h1>Customer Information Collection <br /></h1>
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="custinfo" >
       <table>
       <tr>
            <td><label for="customerid">Customer ID (integer value): </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="customerid" name="customerid" size=11 value="<?php 
    echo $idcus;?>"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $ecus;?></span></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td><label for="customerfname">Customer Frist Name: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="customerfname" name="customerfname" size=50 value="<?php 
    echo $fnamecus;?>"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $ename;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="customerlname">Customer Last Name: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="customerlname" name="customerlname" size=50 value="<?php 
    echo $lnamecus;?>"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $elname;?></span></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td><label for="customeraddress">Customer Address: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="customeraddress" name="customeraddress" size=65/></td>

            <td><label for="suburb"> Suburb: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
        State:<select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="select">--</option>
            <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
            <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
            <option value="NT">NT</option>
            <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
            <option value="SA">SA</option>
            <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
            <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
             <option value="WA">WA</option>
          </select>
     </td>
        <td><label for="postcode"> Post Code: </label><input type="text" id="postcode" 
    name="postcode" size=4 value="<?php 
    echo $pcde;?>"/><span class="error"><?php echo $epcode;?></span></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save Data"/>&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />
      </tr>
      </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The mandatory comment here would be to avoid using mysql functions and instead migrate to PDO or mysqli functions as the first mentioned are deprecated.

Comment: im sorry i study at university and we are currently studying mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `mysql_query` on your `$query` -- right now you're just defining the $query object and then ignoring it for the rest of the page.

Add something like the following on the line before `echo "correct";`

```
$queryResult = mysql_query($query, $conn) 
 or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
```

n.b. I'll echo @Ozmah's comment about looking into PDO or mysqli functions - learning the deprecated plain mysql functions will be of dubious value.

Comment: how stupid of me lol. When i do add that in i get error Problem with queryInvalid utf8 character string: '\x91customerlname' which i have no clue about

Comment: Check to make sure you don't have smart quotes in the $query string - that can really mess you up

Comment: i fixed the smart quotes but a new error arised: Problem with queryIncorrect integer value: 'customerid' for column 'customerID' at row 1

Comment: Hmm...that's another problem entirely.  I'd post another question for that one.